# 18.10 Deja Dup Backup error

Tags: nautilus, backup, deja-dup

When running the back on 18.10 (Deja Dup) to my Google Drive I have several problems.  The most obvious it I get this error message:

```
Giving up after 5 attempts. Error: gdata-service-error-quark: Authentication required: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
 (4)
```

Authorization to my Google Drive is okay (I can see the data in Nautilus).

I also always get a popup box asking for a password for restoring the backup, but I figure this is because I've never made a successful backup.  My Google Drive shows several files that look like this:

```
duplicity-full.(lots of letters and numbers).vol1.difftar.gpg
```

There are dozens of them all 25M in size with today's date.  I figure these are the backup files, so something is writing to the Google Drive, so what need authorization?

Comment: Try coying the backup directory (as a safety measure) then empty the backup directory and try again with the backup.

Comment: Same results, unfortunately.