# Backup failure using Deja Dup with google drive - Invalid Credentials

Tags: 18.04, backup, deja-dup, google-drive

My Ubuntu version is 18.04. The error is as follows which only appears in the middle of uploading backup files:

```
Giving up after 5 attempts. Error: gdata-service-error-quark: Authentication required: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
 (4)
```

I found the this same question [18.10 Deja Dup Backup error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120874/18-10-deja-dup-backup-error) but there is no answer. Also can't find any solution elsewhere.

Another question is that if there is another way to backup Ubuntu with Google drive, without using Deja Dup?

Comment: Does [this reference](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/backup-files-to-google-drive-on-ubuntu) help?

Comment: No, it does not mention the problem.